# KnockoutJS how do I bind change event of select without firing during databinding?

Tags: knockout.js

In KnockoutJS, I have a select that is databound, on adding a change event, I find that my event is being fired when the control is databound (to display the currently selected item). This makes perfect sense, but how can I handle only those  events that are triggered by a user changing the selection?

My Idea is that there may be a way of telling if knockout is currently binding data. I have found that if I use the KO event: binding, I might be able to search the call stack for "notifySubscribers" - I don't like that approach. Does anybody know the proper way to do this?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO subscribing to the observable itself has the correct behavior for that what You want. No need here to listen for the `select` change event. See this example: *(credits: rniemeyer)*:

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, optionsText: 'name', value: choice"></select>

ko.observableArray.fn.find = function(prop, data) {
  var valueToMatch = data[prop]; 
  return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this(), function(item) {
    return item[prop] === valueToMatch; 
  });
};

function ViewModel(choices, choice) {
  this.choices = ko.observableArray(choices);
  this.choice = ko.observable(this.choices.find("id", choice)); 
  this.choice.subscribe(function(v) {
    console.log("Subscription: ",v);
  });
  this.choiceTracker = ko.computed(function() {
    var v = this.choice();
    if(!ko.computedContext.isInitial()) {
      console.log("Computed: ", v);
    }
  }, this);
};

var choices = [
  { id: 1, name: "one" },
  { id: 2, name: "two" },
  { id: 3, name: "three" }
];

var choice = { id: 2, name: "two" };

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(choices, choice));
```

BTW, just look at the evaluation sequence between subscription and computed observable. Notice how the computed is evaluated always after the subscription.

Comment: I'd lost track of this ticket when I found the solution. I shouldn't be listening to select, that's right, however my 'extra' event was being caused when the observable was trying to assert it's value on a droplist that no longer contained it's value. In effect, I was receiving an extra event when the value was cooerced to the default option. Since my default option is empty string, I just made sure that there wasn't an empty string value coming into my subscription handler.